# Why am I getting a NullpointerException on CommandLink click in JSF

Tags: jsf

I am trying to trigger a method in the backing bean on load.
Whenever the link is clicked it throws a NPE , any idea why?, I've included snippets of my code below.

```
   Error:    listener="#{userController.validate}": java.lang.NullPointerException: javax.el.ELException
```

---

```
 <h:form id="reg">
        <h:outputLabel value="Promo" /> :
        <h:inputText id="promocode" value="#{userController.promocode}">
            <f:ajax render=":promoimage" event="blur" listener="#{userController.validate}"/>
        </h:inputText>   
        <h:commandLink id="dummyclick" value="link">
            <f:ajax event="click" render=":promoimage" listener="#{userController.validate}"/>
        </h:commandLink>    
 </h:form>
```

---

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userController", eager= true)
@SessionScoped
public class UserController implements Serializable {
    public void validate(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
        ........
        }
}
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("reg:dummyclick").click();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the ajax call and it worked, it was probably pointless in this case. I'd still like to know why it is throwing an NPE though.

```
<h:commandLink id="dummyclick" value="link" action="#{userController.showPromo}">
</h:commandLink>
```

.......

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("reg:dummyclick").click();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you using command link, instead of that use command button and if you set required="true" for inputtext, it will automatically check validation on same button.